# operation on 2 dimensional hash map C++

Tags: c++, hashmap

I am currently working on a coding question:

Given an array of strings, return all groups of strings that are anagrams.

For example, Given:

```
{asch, scah, bva, vba, soa}
```

return

```
{ {asch, scah}, {bva, vba}, {soa}}
```

To solve this question less than O(n^2) time, we should firstly sort each word, and group the sorted words in one set, if the sorted words are the same.

I wanted to use two-dimensional hashmap.

```
map<string, map<int,string>> container;
```

to use this two-dimensional hashmap, the first key is the sorted word, the second key is its index in the original sequence, and the value is the original word.

```
for(int i=0; i<sequence.size();i++)
{
    string original_word = sequence[i];
    string sorted_word = original_word;
    sort(sorted_word.begin(),sorted_word.end());
    container[sorted_word][i] = original_word;

}
```

After this loop, I believe all the anagrams which must have the same sorted_word, will be grouped into the first level of hashmap.

My question is, how should I write the code in order to get the set which has the same sorted_word?

Can I do

```
for( iterator itr = container.begin(); itr != container.end(); itr++)
{
     auto grouped_words = itr.second(); // what is the data type of grouped_word here?
}
```

correct me if there is anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, it is map<string, map<int,string>> container;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a mistake here:

```
vector<string, vector<int,string>> container;  // ???
```

As in your question you speak about hash maps, I suppose that you meant:

```
unordered_map<string, unordered_map<int,string>> container;
```

In this case, you can use the result as follows:

```
for( auto itr = container.begin(); itr != container.end(); itr++)
    {
        auto &grouped_words = itr->second; // prefer a reference
        cout << itr->first<<": "; 
        for (auto &x : grouped_words) {
            cout << "\t" << x.first << ":"<< x.second<<endl; 
        }
    }
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/9Axic1).

**Edit**:  `grouped_words` is (here) a reference to an `unordered_map<int, string>`